# Suggestions for books about surf music of the 60s

Tags: style

Can anyone suggest some books about surf music in the 60s? I've seen some books about individual artists, but would like to read something about the genre as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbeat Books' [Surf Beat : Rock 'n' Roll's Forgotten Revolution](http://www.halleonardbooks.com/product/viewproduct.action?itemid=333078) would seem to fit the bill.

Arcadia Publishing's [Southern California Surf Music, 1960-1966](https://www.arcadiapublishing.com/9781467133203/Southern-California-Surf-Music-1960-1966) might also be of interest.

Comment: Thanks, TM! I just got *Surf Beat* from Amazon and started reading it. Great book! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @BobBroadley I always feel Surf deserves a proper revival one day - it was all over a bit too fast (not that I was around then!)